# Stability problem when using an OpAmp to drive a BJT for high current application

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, high-current, stability

I am designing a circuit for my lab, and in that application I need to have several low noise current source driving coils at roughly 7V, 20A. I could not find a benchtop power supply cheap enough so I thought I could try build my own.
[image: Simplified schematic]

When I am testing this part of the circuit, where a op amp drives two transistors connected in Darlinton emitter-follwer configuration, there is stability problem. Although I am not an expert of this kind of circuit, I know I need to add a capacitor to limit the bandwidth, so I put a capacitor there to compensates. I have tried 4.7uF and 47uF on that position, and it helps a little bit. The entire circuit went from completely unstable to having a 60~80kHz, ~100mV pk-pk oscillation. However, adding a 47uF capacitor (bipolar electrolitic) on top of a 4.7uF ceramic capacitor I first put in did not help much in terms of stability. Simulation on LTSpice tells me that it is stable even with a few uF. Is there something wrong about the design? What should I try/learn next?

Also, I have tried to profile the transfer function of the darlington connected transistors without op-amp, it depends a little on the biasing condition, but even in the worst case it has a corner frequency of 100kHz. I would like to have the closed loop circuit response at frequency not significantly lower than that (maybe 20kHz?).
[image]
In addition, the op-amp I actually use in my circuit is OPA188, I thought there specs are similar. Is there something weird with rail-to-rail op-amps like OPA188, and is there a good part if the op amp choice is the issue?

Many thanks!

Comment: Try adding a resistor [here](https://i.imgur.com/BMF2s9v.png). Also your simulation load is a resistor which is not a very accurate model of a solenoid at kHz. You should not actually need a capacitor at all for stability because your follower has no voltage gain and presents negligible capacitive loading.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I thought about that resistor breifly, the point should be having the impedance of the capacitor be smaller than the feedback resistance at the desired bandwidth, so the feedback is bypassed by the capacitor? Then a larger feedback resistance should gives higher stability? However in simulation when I put a 10Ohm resistor it seems to be stable, but a 1k resistor makes it oscillate in sim. I am confused.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Also I thought the BJT's parasitic junction capacitance has a capacitive load and is the cause of my stability problem? Are you saying they are not signifcant enough?   Also I have the same simulation for inductive load as well, I just omitted it in the picture for clarity. I am testing with resistive load for now and oscillation are present even with resistive load.

Comment: You say you want "low noise" but how low? Please specify the amount of current ripple (or rms current noise) you want in your inductor. Also the inductor value and DCR would help.

Comment: @bobflux The DCR is ~0.5Ohm, L~0.5mH, I want 20A with <1mA ripple, and definitely 1mA DC stability (against thermal drift etc. I plan to use a INA240A2 + 5mOhm shunt to measure current and have slower feedback on that). Power efficiency is not too much a concern, as long as the cooling requirement is not too crazy (watercooling is OK if needed). I thought about a PWM design but I am a bit scared about high-frequency noise. My experiment require very stable B field and can always benefit from lower noise if possible.

Comment: @bobflux Simple back-of-envelop calculation gives me that 10V signal at 1MHz gives 10V/(0.5mH*1MHz*2pi) = 3mA. Still a bit too high, maybe I can apply a LC filter first before the load. And I thought doing a 1MHz PWM is not trivial either? Maybe I can pick up some high frequency buck converter IC, and modify the design so I can vary the voltage to vary the current?  I could give that a try, but not sure which way is easier.

Comment: If you want high current accuracy in the solenoid, I assume this is because you want an accurate magnetic field? Have you considered measuring the magnetic field itself with a Hall sensor inside the solenoid? That would get rid of that annoying ultra low value current shunt resistor, and the associated low offset opamp, etc.

Comment: It is doable with a switching solution, but if this is a one-off and you need a solution RIGHT NOW, then a linear solution is quicker and simpler. But you say you need "several" current sources ; if you need two, okay, but if you need ten of these, the lower cost and much smaller footprint of the switching solution would really pay off.

Comment: What is the duty cycle? I mean, the solenoid is going to dissipate at least 140W, so it better be cooled properly. If the solenoid temperature rise limits your duty cycle, you might be able to cheat on the size of the heat sink too. Also, what is the minimum current? You could hack a solution with high power switching constant current LED drivers, with a LC filter to get rid of the ripple, and an extra opamp to accurately regulate the current, but these don't regulate current down to zero. If you're fine with a minimum value of current, that could work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to examine the output impedance of each stage and ensure it is much lower than the load over the entire bandwidth you would like (20kHz).

This is not the case in your design.  The Op Amp cannot drive a std 47uF e-cap with an ESR~ 4 ohms or let  alone a low ESR cap ~ < 200 mOhms. It has output
It high out impedance that is only reduced by negative feedback and if the gain “sucks” or is current limited you have lost your gain at some frequency ( where it usually oscillates or is saturated at one rail).

To drive a large coil with 20A demands many low Rce power transistors in parallel and preferably several cascaded complementary emitter followers with no caps in the loop for unity gain.

You could also use a MOSFET Half bridge which is more efficient.

Your design lacks good specs for Impedances, current limits and GBW thus as a consequence you maybe made invalid choices for every part and configuration in the design. It must be push-pull if you are driving AC current thru a coil to match your input voltage.

You may need several Darlington’s ganged I parallel to lower the output impedance and add a large CPU cooler heat sink. Try [this](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2043%2010%2042%0At%20256%20192%20320%20192%200%201%20-5.359823405427049%200.6373031999375245%20100%0At%20256%20288%20320%20288%200%20-1%2013.3655701946979%20-0.6373031999375263%20100%0Aw%20320%20208%20320%20240%200%0Aw%20320%20240%20320%20272%200%0Aw%20320%20304%20320%20352%200%0Ar%20256%20288%20256%20352%200%20220%0Ar%20256%20192%20256%20128%200%20220%0Ad%20256%20240%20256%20288%202%20default%0AR%20256%20240%20192%20240%200%201%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20256%20352%20320%20352%200%0Aw%20256%20128%20320%20128%200%0Aw%20320%20128%20320%20176%200%0AR%20256%20128%20256%2080%200%200%2040%2010%200%200%200.5%0AR%20256%20352%20256%20400%200%200%2040%20-10%200%200%200.5%0Ad%20256%20192%20256%20240%202%20default%0Aw%20320%20240%20400%20240%200%0Ar%20400%20240%20432%20240%200%201%0Ag%20400%20352%20400%20384%200%0AO%20448%20160%20496%20160%200%0Ao%208%2064%200%204098%206%200.025%200%202%208%203%0Ao%2018%2064%200%204098%200.000091552734375%200.00009765625%201%201%0A).

Comment: The coil won’t conduct much current above 10kHz. https://tinyurl.com/yexevsen

Comment: Thanks for the advice! If I understood correctly, the trick of a capacitor (which I thought is the standard trick of external compensation for stability) don't work in this case because the open-loop output impedance is high (100Ohm when I checked datasheet). The circuit you showed would work better because properly biased diode has low AC impedance. Are you suggesting having that circuit in the loop? Alternatively, maybe I can bring the BJT out of the op amp loop, and have other op amps form PID circuit to deal with it (which I need for the full project anyways).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I understand now reducing output impedance seen by the BJT is the key. The coil will operate mostly DC, unipolar. The bandwidth requirement is only for switching it /jumping the current fast enough and eat away noise. It is not super critical, but I still want to keep it high if possible. The plan is to have 2~3 transistors share load and water-cool them if needed. The actual load would be ~0.5Ohm and 0.5mH.

Comment: I would use 5 mohm FETs 1% of DCR with PWM but OA is not fast enough so a proper half bridge is better with a PWM

Comment: Maybe I can use a LTC6992 to convert analog voltage into a 1MHz PWM signal, then use a gate driver to drive low R mosfets, and use high-order (maybe 4?) LC filter at 10kHz cutoff to filter out the switching noise. It is just a bit conceptually difficult and that is why I did not try it initially. Maybe worth a try.

Comment: Yes that will work. I would suggest current control and feedback for a stable system with slew rate limiting on input control using a motor ESC or full bridge rated to match or exceed current load with oscillating acceleration doubling the voltage and current.